# Getting some chinese characters when trying to access google play username with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting some chinese characters when trying to access google play username with Unity3D:

```
 void Start () {

    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
   // Social.localUser.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;


    Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Authentication successful");
            userInfo =  Social.localUser.userName ;
            Debug.Log(userInfo);
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("Authentication failed");
    });



}
 void Update () {

        txt = GameObject.Find("txt").GetComponent<Text>();

        txt.text = userInfo;

    }

}
```

I have checked if user is really authenticated with google play, and he is. I'm getting this error on my mobile phone (Samsung S6).
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, solved by updating [google play games plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem as well with the 0.9.38 version of [GPGS](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). They committed a fix 2 days ago (v0.9.38a) that appears to have fixed the issue. From the [commit log](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/commits/master):

> Fixing string marshaling from C to C#.

Make sure you follow the [upgrade instructions](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/UPGRADING.txt) when upgrading.